# Calling private function from external - where are referenced type parameters stored in the end?

Tags: memory, calldata, private

Let's assume we have something like:

```
contract C {
   function externalFunction(uint256[] calldata data) external {
      privateFunction(data);
   }

   function privateFunction(uint256[] memory data) private {
   }
}
```

If I access `data` from within `externalFuction` it will read it from `calldata`, since it is referenced type, thus saving gas. But what will happen when it gets to `internalFunction`? Will it create a `memory` copy of array or will it read it from the same location since it will JUMP there from `externalFunction`?

Referenced documentation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Anybody knows anything about this matter?